# Custom control paint event doesn't work

Tags: c#, custom-controls

Custom control add into its parent. in parent form 's `form_lord()`. Custom control paint event doesn't work (breakpoint at custom control onpaint event even can't fire)

The code is like this (I don't know why):

custom control:

```
public class Box : Control
{
    public Rectangle rect; 

    public Box(Rectangle rect)
    {
        this.rect = rect;
    } 

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Chocolate), rect);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    } 
} 

public partial class Form1 : Form
{ 
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Box box = new Box( new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 130) );

        this.Controls.add(box);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Which breakpoint and where? Under what conditions? Your question is heavily under-specified.

Comment: breakpoint at customcontrol 's onpaint

Comment: Your rect value is (100, 100, 100, 130), but your box control's dimensions are (0, 0, 0, 0).  sa_ddam213's answer demonstrates this but doesn't explain it.  The width and height of the control is separate from the width and height of your rect value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the controls width and height, this solution below woks for me

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Load +=new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Box box = new Box(new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
            box.Width = 200;
            box.Height = 200;
            this.Controls.Add(box);
        } 

    }

    public class Box : Control
    {
        public Rectangle rect;

        public Box(Rectangle rect)
        {
            this.rect = rect;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Chocolate), rect);
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }



    }
```

Comment: thanks.yes,it works.but I am confused.because I think width and height =200 doesn't work  , the rect 's width and height is 100 which defined in custom control onpaint

Answer (score 0):

Try inheriting `Box` from `UserControl`.